# VB.NET textbox changed but still hold initial value

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, user-controls, textbox

I've never come across this before:

I have a series of text boxes. The text of these boxes get set on page load. then I have a submit button that calls a sub to update the table with the new values (text) in the text box. The problem is it is keeping the original text not the text that is CURRENTLY in the textbox. Anyone come across this before? Or know how to get round it?

Here is the code from my submit button event:

```
 Protected Sub btnSubmit_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles btnSubmit.Click

    Dim Emails As Integer = txtEmails.Text
    Dim Calls As Integer = txtCalls.Text
    Dim Contacts As Integer = txtContacts.Text
    Dim Tasks As Integer = txtTasks.Text
    Dim Meetings As Integer = txtMeetings.Text
    Dim Proposals As Integer = txtProposals.Text
    Dim Points As Integer = txtPoint.Text

    Dim dt As New DataTable()
    Try
        connection.Open()

        Dim sqlCmd As New SqlCommand("UPDATE tblActivityParameters SET Emails = " & Emails & ", Calls = " & Calls & ", Contacts=" & Contacts & ", Tasks =" & Tasks & ", Meetings=" & Meetings & ", Proposals=" & Proposals & ",Points =" & Points, connection)

        Dim sqlDa As New SqlDataAdapter(sqlCmd)

        sqlDa.Fill(dt)
        lblError.Visible = True
        lblError.Text = "Parameters successfully updated"
    Catch SQLExp As SqlException
        lblError.Visible = True
        lblError.Text = "SQL Error: " + SQLExp.Message.ToString()
    Finally
        connection.Close()
    End Try
    GetParameters()
End Sub
```

Cheers,

Jonesy

Comment: Do you have any code you can post for your submit button event?

Comment: I've edited my post with my code for the submit button event

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please check if you have made sure you have checked for IspostBack on the pageload.

```
if not(Me.IsPostBack) then

'fetch the values for initial load

end if
```

Sorry if the syntax is wrong since I am a C# guy.

HTH

Comment: thats just the ticket! thanks. I did: 

        If isPostBack = False Then

And it worked a treat! Cheers

--Jonesy

Comment: Hi again got another problem that stems from the above. I have another page that has the same problem but its a bit different. this is my page load: 

Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load 

If IsPostBack = True Then 

If TextBox1.Text <> String.Empty Then 

CheckDate()

 End If 

End If 

End Sub

 When I postback from clicking the submit button I DON'T want to do the textbox1 if statement. Is there a way I can say if button1 caused postback do this.. else do this...?